# Editable content on your site

Tags: web-development

I see a lot of customers wants to see their content editable. The problem is what to use? I have done one project using WordPress but I think for lightweight sites it is pointless. Also I have worked with ASP.NET MVC but it's for heavy projects too. In what direction I should to look, something like CakePHP or even Django? What can you suggest?

Comment: What features do the websites need apart from an edition interface? No visitor forms, shopping carts or anything?

Comment: wikimatrix.org has a comparison/selection tools you might want to check out.  Maybe mediawiki.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into jekyll + github pages? Unlike wordpress it doesn't run a backend database. It generates HTML,CSS,JS and can be deployed automatically on github, some modifcations on amazon s3, etc.

The advantage of this is less overall maintenance and updates for the site, but managing client-end content might be a pain IF it has to be updated a lot. Not only that, load page times from my experience are 2-3xs faster than wordpress at a fraction of the cost (or even free through github pages)

For CMS management, you could look into things that manage that end for the clients. I've not personally used it but I've heard about Jekyll+CloudCannon+host (github or amazon s3)

http://cloudcannon.com/

Jekyll's got some nice-looking copycat wordpress themes so it might be worth looking into

http://jekyllthemes.org/

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason not to use Wordpress if people are comfortable with it, even if it is for such a small site.  The user interface is easy for most people.  If you're going to go down a pre-build CMS route, then you could look at:

- [Joomla](https://www.joomla.org/)
- [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/)

Both allow the users to change contents fairly easily, though Drupal does (or did when I looked at it) have a bigger learning curve in my opinion.

If you go down the CakePHP route, that's a framework which would require you to build the CMS for the user to edit, so it's what you're looking for out of the box.  If you're going to build your own CMS, then there would be other frameworks to consider too, depending on the platform you're going to host it on.

I've got no experience with Django to comment on that.